# How to call parent's function in react native?

Tags: react-native

How to call the parent's function in the child component?
I followed this answer, but it doesn't work for me. How to solve this?
[React native how to call functions of parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280879/react-native-how-to-call-functions-of-parent-class)
This is my code.

> Parent

```
<View>
    <HeaderHome onClick={this.openDrawer} />
</View>

openDrawer() {
    alert('I am clicked.')
}
```

> Child component

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.bind(this.props.onClick)} >
    <Image source={url} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take it a try:

Parent

```js
<View>
    <HeaderHome onClick={this.openDrawer} />
</View>

openDrawer = () => {
    alert('I am clicked.')
}
```

Children

```js
<TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => { this.props.onClick()}} >
    <Image source={url} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. Forward please teach me more. 
Let me send you my recommendation in every post. Thank you again.